# jQuery .val() problems getting and setting

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have been using jQuery for a while and this makes no sense to me.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?  I have a hidden field , `<asp:HiddenField ID="hidIsValid" runat="server" />`  and I have this code assigning a value to it.

This took me hours to decide to try to change the way I set the value , and now it works , but it appears this is the wrong way:

```
  $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val("true");  **This line never worked
  $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val() = "true";  **this line does work
```

I comes from here , I took out a lot of the code ,this is just ot show the pertinent lines.

```
      function fnValidateAttendees() {
       // $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val("true");  **This line never worked
        $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val() = "true";            
        $('.tFirstName, .tLastName').each(function () {
            if (!($(this).val().match(/^[a-z -']+$/))) {                    
                $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val("false"); //**this line works
            }              
        });
        $('.tPhoneNumber').each(function () {
            if (!($(this).val().match(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/))) {                   
                $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val("false"); //**this line works
            }
        });
        $('.tEmail').each(function () {
            if (!($(this).val().match(/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/))) {
                $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val("false"); //this line works
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

can someone make sense of this

Comment: Assigning a string to a string doesn't make any sense indeed. Maybe you could post the rendered (client-side) output of that JS?

Comment: What makes you think that the second one work? That's impossible.

Comment: its getting late , I do not know , it doesn't make sense , basically i have other code right before setting the value to the string "false" I also change css settings , and they get changed on in invalid entry and the hidden value immediatly gets set to "false" in dom , then when the function gets called again the css changes to valid and the line to change hid value to "true" never changed and hid value always stayed at "false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you make out that this does not work..

Setting the value using .val() will not be reflected in the DOM immediately..

Maybe that's the reason you feel its not working..

Also this does not make any sense..

```
$('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val() = "true";
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to a result of a function ..  Its illegal

Comment: I know its illegal , that's why I asked , I chose your answer because I think "Setting the value using .val() will not be reflected in the DOM immediately.."  was my problem

Comment: How can I make it set the value in the dom right away?  without loosing all the values in the inputs?

Comment: you can use .attr()..  $('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').attr('value' , 'true');  .. This will behave like setAttribute and the changes will be immediately reflected in the DOM..

Comment: Why do you care if it's in the DOM, as long as the property is set? Actually, there's one case where it matters: if the user presses the Reset button, the DOM value will be the new default.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `attr` jQuery API to set the value.

```
$('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').attr('value','true');
```

or try removing the quotations.

```
$('#<%= hidIsValid.ClientID %>').val(true);
```